# PySide and VTK on Windows 32

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyside, vtk

I've got a PySide/VTK application, connected using the QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.
PySide 1.0.9 works ok on Unix based systems with a QT4.8/VTK 5.8. (all Python 2.7.3)

Then I port on a Microsoft Windows system (XP 32), with PySide win32 distribution (1.1.x)  Qt4 and VTK 5.10, and I have a type error in QVTKRenderWindowInteractor while retrieving the self.winId() which is expected to be castable as int:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PyCObject'
```

The PySide API actually says the PySide.QtGui.QWidget.winId() returns a long...

I'm starting some more tests on both MS-Windows and Unix, but maybe some of you could give me a piece of advice?
What and where do I have to look for?

Could it be related to a bad cast of this **long** on a **32bits** system, produced by the PySide interface generator to Qt?

see line 152 
http://sourceforge.net/p/pycgns/code/ci/17b696c3b0ad2b387b7e0ddc5d9b195cbc6abf70/tree/NAVigater/CGNS/NAV/Q7VTKRenderWindowInteractor.py

Comment: Registered as a PySide bug: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-46 and fixed using the hint described in this bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this row by:

```
WId = self.winId()

if type(WId).__name__ == 'PyCObject':
    from ctypes import pythonapi, c_void_p, py_object

    pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr.restype  = c_void_p
    pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr.argtypes = [py_object]

    WId = pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(WId)

self._RenderWindow.SetWindowInfo(str(int(WId)))
```